# Adding a doctype breaks background image alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, doctype

Currently I have the below HTML code, as you can see there is no doctype specified:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
        <!--[if gt IE 7]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" media="screen" />
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="searchbar">
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-append">
                        <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" />
                        <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mixed with the following style.css file:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Comfortaa;
    src: url('Comfortaa.ttf');
}

body{
    background-color: #77d5fb;
    background-image: url('bottom_bg.jpg');
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Comfortaa;
}

#searchbar{
    width:700px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -350px;
}
```

Having that code shows my background image just fine however when I add the `<!DOCTYPE html>` as is required by bootstrap, my background image declaration seems to be *"ignored"* and only the specified background color is shown.

I have done some testing and found that background-position is causing the issue.

With `background-position: center bottom` the image will not appear however `background-image: center` and it will appear but centered at the top of the page and I need it at the bottom.

How can I push down that background image?

Comment: @Fags Don't use that `doctype` anymore.  That's old school.  Use the HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
html,body{min-height:100%}
```

to your CSS.

As for the doctype, use this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

so your document will look somewhat like this working example. Try it and you'll see the image is displayed just the way you want it to be displayed.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Title Here</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  html{
      min-height:100%;
  }
  body{
      min-height:100%;
      background-color: #77d5fb;
      background-image: url('bottom_bg.jpg');
      background-position: center bottom;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-family: Comfortaa;
  }
  #searchbar{
      width:700px;
      height:200px;
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      margin:-100px 0 0 -350px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p id="searchbar">Just testing!</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You should always use a `doctype`, otherwise you will be developing in the scary and unpredictable land called quirksmode, this is nothing you want. I suggest you add:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and try to fix your minor CSS issues with that in place.

Comment: With that added, why doesn't the "background-position: center bottom;" work as it should?

Comment: I bet it is.  Link to your page.  If your content isn't taking up the full height of the browser window then it would "appear" as if it wasn't at the bottom.